# How to commit and push code in bitbucket/GitHub through programming

Tags: git, github-api, bitbucket-api

I am planning to create static basic CMS using nodeJs and static JSON where (on runtime) on click of submit button changes gets committed in the repository.

Use case: end user can perform CRUD operation using static UI and all the changes should get committed and pushed in GIT repository

Comment: Using their API(s)?

Comment: Use [Github API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) or [Bitbucket API](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a starting point: https://github.com/ConfusedDeer/Git-Captain

It uses a Node.js back-end and HTML/JS front end.

> Client requests --> Node.js HTTPS server (hosted on Linux or Windows Server) --> GitHub API

I created this solution because I needed to be able to create, delete, and search branches in multiple repos in one fell swoop for a product I was building that required multiple repositories.

Some features:

1. Handles authentication by creating an OAUTH App in Git-Hub.
2. Auto logOff for user timeout and revokes the token.
3. If the GitHub API is down it won't let users login to the front-end site.
4. Keeps a success/failure log of actions taken by the user with links to the GitHub repos.
5. Search for branches across multiple repos.
6. Create new branches across multiple repos.
7. Delete branches across multiple repos.
8. Search for open pull requests across multiple repos